# Ajax call syntax error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have below code in processor.php to view a image from database on the same page using jQuery ajax method. downloading image part is done on another PHP called solve.php. Image is not shown on same page and firebug errors are;

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" 
     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
        $(document).ready( function() {
            $(".image-view").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var url = $(this).attr('href'); // Get href attribute of current element
                $.ajax({
                    url: url, // Use url with arguments
                    type: "GET",

                    success: function(data){ //function to be called if request succeeds
                        $("#preview").html(data); // It should be html here
                    }
                });
            }) //line 20
        });
  </script>
```

**screenshot**

[image]

What is a cause?

> SyntaxError: missing } after function body
>       processor.php (line 20, col 5)
>
> SyntaxError: missing } after function body  processor.php (line 20,
>   col 5)
>
> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'  processor.php (line 21,
>   col 2)

Comment: i think you missing in ; in line 20 so add  }); in line 20

Comment: Is that your whole code? There are no syntax errors there, and the line you've marked as line 20 is not the 20th line.

Comment: This is pretty much an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36845479/ajax-firebug-error which was posted a day before.